# Socat virt tty Hardware flow control

Tags: socat

I am using socat to create a virtual serial port connection to a TCP client in Linux

eg sudo socat pty,link=/dev/ttyVirt0,raw,echo=0 tcp:192.168.1.251:5001&

This all works fine but one of the 3rd party applications I use with this virtual serial port uses hardware flow control. While flow control is not needed for the virtual serial port, I need to be able to assert RTS (logic 0) from the virual port ttyVirt0 to enable this application using it to send data.

There must be a command line option to support this? Does anyone know?